# How do I choose the URL for my Spring Boot webapp?

Tags: url, web-applications, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot to create a web app, and I am not sure how to change the URL from `localhost:8080` to something like `localhost:8080/myWebApp`.

I have a seen a lot of resources online referencing an `application.properties` file and adding that to the classpath. But, I'm not sure exactly where to put that.

#### Questions

- In my `src/main/resources`?
- How would I assign the URL within the file?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You need to set the property `server.contextPath` to `/myWebApp`.

Check out [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) part of the documentation

The easiest way to set that property would be in the properties file you are using (most likely `application.properties`) but Spring Boot provides a whole lot of different way to set properties. Check out [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-property-launcher-features) part of the documentation

**EDIT**

As has been mentioned by @AbdullahKhan, as of Spring Boot 2.x the property has been deprecated and should be replaced with `server.servlet.contextPath` as has been correctly mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48987109/2504224) answer.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly, except now my messaging system isn't functioning correctly. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: @Glad that it worked! There could be various reasons that your messaging system doesn't work. If you need help finding it, it would probably be best to start a new SO question so every one can see without being distracted by the current one

Comment: N.B. you can also set `server.servlet-path` if you want to put other stuff in the root context "/".

Comment: Be sure to include leading "/" so it should be "/myWebApp"

Comment: How do you enforce this to only work with RestControllers and access the  normal Controllers without the context?

Comment: @Stoan I can't think of any way to do that

Comment: @geoand Thanks anyway, I will try this solution in the min time, http://stackoverflow.com/a/32943991/1458556

Comment: server.contextPath is getting ignored and it's pointing with war file name

Comment: @devo It would probably be best to start a new question containing the specifics of your problem

Comment: As of spring boot 2 the `server.contextPath` property is deprecated. Use `server.servlet.contextPath` instead. Check out  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48987109/3094731) answer.

Comment: If you set server.servlet.contextPath on the command line it overrides what is set in the application.properties file

Comment: @ssimm yes, that is standard spring boot behavior

Answer (score 21):

As of spring boot 2 the `server.contextPath` property is deprecated. Instead you should use `server.servlet.contextPath`.

So in your application.properties file add:

`server.servlet.contextPath=/myWebApp`

For more details see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#servlet-specific-server-properties

Answer (score 17):

In your `src/main/resources` put an `application.properties` or `application.yml` and put a `server.contextPath` in there.

```
server.contextPath=/your/context/here
```

When starting your application the application will be available at `http://localhost:8080/your/context/here`.

For a comprehensive list of properties to set see [Appendix A.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) of the Spring Boot reference guide.

Instead of putting it in the application.properties you can also pass it as a system property when starting your application

```
java -jar yourapp.jar -Dserver.contextPath=/your/path/here
```

Comment: `server.context-path` is now deprecated, use `server.contextPath` now

Comment: @dspies those are actually the same... You can use camel casing or use a `-` both will work.

Comment: How do you enforce this to only work with RestControllers and access the  normal Controllers without the context?

Comment: server.contextPath in my application.properties is ignored :( 
Running Spring v1.4.2.RELEASE on Tomcat 8.5.6

Comment: @ChristianSchäfer: That is the case for me too, in Eclipse. My `@SpringBootApplication` class name is always my context root.Were you able to solve it? I am using 1.5.3.

Comment: server.contextPath is getting ignored and it's pointing with war file name.

Comment: @devo if you are deploying a war file to a tomcat instance most of the `server.*` properties are useless as those are for configuring the embedded tomcat.

Comment: @M.Deinum is there any solution to achieve custom URL here in spring boot?

Comment: Ask a question for that (or search the question). You are deploying an app (regardless of the fact that it is a spring boot app) so the normal rules apply then.

Answer (score 5):

In Spring Boot 2 the property in e.g. `application.properties` is `server.servlet.context-path=/myWebApp` to set the context path.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_custom_context_path

Answer (score 1):

The server.contextPath or server.context-path works if

in pom.xml

1. packing should be war not jar
2. Add following dependencies

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <!-- Tomcat/TC server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
   ```

   In eclipse, right click on project --> Run as --> Spring Boot App.

Comment: 1. packing should be war not jar - Not correct. It works for Jar type too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue of changing the context path of a Spring application is handled very well in the post titled [Spring Boot Change Context Path](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-path)

Basically the post discusses multiple ways of realizing this viz.

1. Java Config
2. Command Line Arguments
3. Java System Properties
4. OS Environment Variables
5. application.properties in Current Directory
6. application.properties in the classpath (src/main/resources or the
   packaged jar file)