# How to change project mapping in Spring Boot Application?

Tags: spring-boot, mapping

I'm working on a Spring rest project with Spring Boot. I follow this instructions https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/. 
When I run the project, project is working on localhost:8080 as described in the tutorial. But I wanna run this project on localhost:8080/ProjectName. How can I change the project mapping?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452072/how-do-i-choose-the-url-for-my-spring-boot-webapp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't already have one, add an application.properties file to src\main\resources. In that properties file, add 2 properties:

```
server.contextPath=/ProjectName
server.port=8080
```

The server.port=8080 is optional

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I didn't have a properties file and I did your answer. Everything is okey.