# Why does the endpoint path change with @SpringBootApplication?

Tags: spring

If I run my project with Tomcat a valid REST call would look like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest-api/dl4j/we/getModelInfo?modelName=123
```

However, if I start it from within a Java main method with `@SpringBootApplication` I have to call

```
http://localhost:8080/api/dl4j/we/getModelInfo?modelName=123
```

How can I ensure that this path stays the same for all REST controller?

This is how I run the server programmatically:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {         
        LOGGER.info("EasyModelAccessServer Server is shutting down.");}
    ));

    SpringApplication.run(EasyModelAccessServer.class, args);
}
```

Comment: what have you set for your server.contextPath ? have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452072/how-do-i-choose-the-url-for-my-spring-boot-webapp)

Comment: @SasiKathimanda Interesting - it seems like Spring never used my application.properties because there it actually says `api/` - The question then would be why it ignored that as I started the server directly with Tomcat from within Eclipse O_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context path is determined by the servlet container. For example, Tomcat used the file name of the war copied into the web apps directory.
In a external WAR deployment, with Tomcat `server.xml` configured with a connector, you cannot specify this in the application configuration (`application.yml` or `application.properties`).