# How to add "api" prefix to all controllers under one package com.myproject.api?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-webflow

I was trying to find it but I found many different scenarios but not this one.

What I want to do is to add "/api/" prefix to all routes in controllers under com.myproject.api .
I want "/api/*" for all controllers under package com.myapp.api and no prefix for all controllers under com.myapp.web

Is it possible with Spring / Spring Boot ?

Comment: This is not the same.

Answer (score 7):

With Spring Boot, this worked for me :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.addPathPrefix("/api",
               HandlerTypePredicate.forBasePackage("com.your.package"));
    }
}
```

Comment: We can find an equivalent example there : https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.0-M1/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-path-matching

Comment: Great! And the `HandlerTypePredicate` can be use to predicate class with `@RestController` annotation!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using springboot, you can add the following:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api
```

to application.properties file.

Comment: This isn't what was being asked. The question is for handlers in a given package, such that things like /login are not moved to within the /api sub-path

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the result I think you are looking for in the following way, so long as you are using MVC.

First make a configuration class that implements `WebMvcRegistrations`

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcRegistrations {

    @Value("${Prop.Value.String}") //"api"
    private String apiPrefix;

    @Value("${Prop.Package.Names}") //["com.myapp.api","Others if you like"]
    private String[] prefixedPackages;

    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping getRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        return new PrefixedApiRequestHandler(apiPrefix,prefixedPackages);
    }
}
```

Then create a class that extends `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`
and overrides `getMappingForMethod`

```
@Log4j2
public class PrefixedApiRequestHandler extends RequestMappingHandlerMapping {

    private final String prefix;

    private final String[] prefixedPackages;

    public PrefixedApiRequestHandler(final String prefix, final String... packages) {
        super();
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.prefixedPackages = packages.clone();

    }

    @Override
    protected RequestMappingInfo getMappingForMethod(final Method method, final Class<?> handlerType) {

        RequestMappingInfo info = super.getMappingForMethod(method, handlerType);
        if (info == null) {
            return null;
        }

        for (final String packageRef : prefixedPackages) {
            if (handlerType.getPackageName().contains(packageRef)) {
                info = createPrefixedApi().combine(info);

                log.trace("Updated Prefixed Mapping " + info);
                return info;
            }
        }
        log.trace("Skipped Non-Prefixed Mapping " + info);
        return info;
    }

    private RequestMappingInfo createPrefixedApi() {
        String[] patterns = new String[prefix.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++) {
            // Build the URL prefix
            patterns[i] = prefix;
        }

        return new RequestMappingInfo(
                new PatternsRequestCondition(patterns,
                        getUrlPathHelper(),
                        getPathMatcher(),
                        useSuffixPatternMatch(),
                        useTrailingSlashMatch(),
                        getFileExtensions()),
                new RequestMethodsRequestCondition(),
                new ParamsRequestCondition(),
                new HeadersRequestCondition(),
                new ConsumesRequestCondition(),
                new ProducesRequestCondition(),
                null);
    }
}
```

You should then see /api/(ControllerMapping) for all mappings, in the specified packages only. Note: I have `@RequestMapping("/")` at the top of my controller.

Comment: something is wrong with patterns[ i ]  array filling in here. Why do we fill it in by duplicating pattern the same count of times as has pattern.length? so if pattern is 'internal' we'll have 8 copies of the pattern

Comment: NOTE: most of the constructors/objects used here are deprecated in Spring5

Answer (score -1):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452072/how-do-i-choose-the-url-for-my-spring-boot-webapp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405474/add-context-path-to-spring-boot-application).

Add an `application.properties` file under src/main/resources, with the following option:

```
server.contextPath=/api
```

Check the official reference for [common properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Comment: I do not want to add Base url for all. I am building app with front-end with templates AND api which I want to prefix

Comment: You want com.myproject.api/** for HTML views and com.myproject.api/api/** for your other controllers (such as REST controllers)?

Comment: No. I want "/api/*" for all controllers under package com.myapp.api and no prefix for all controllers under com.myapp.web

Answer (score -1):

You should add `@RequestMapping("/api")` to top of every desired `@Controller` or `@RestController` class.

When both the class and method have that annotation, Spring Boot appends them while building the url. In below example the method will be bound to `/api/user` route.

```
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RestController
public class MyController {

  @RequestMapping("/user")
  public List<User> getUsers(){
     return ...
  }

}
```

Comment: ' top of every desired Controller or RestController class.' - so it is not impossible to configure Spring somehow to do that? It would be easier to maintain

Comment: What you're saying is package level annotations but Spring's `@RequestMapping` does not support it.

Comment: can't be done somehow as server.contextPath but applied only to package?