# How to configure context path using Spark-Java

Tags: java, spark-java

How can you configure context path using `com.sparkjava:spark-core` with jetty?

*EDIT:*

Instead of root app context being `http://mydomain.xyz` the app would be accessed through `http://mydomain.xyz/custom-context`.

[see this post on the same subject but in spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452072/how-do-i-choose-the-url-for-my-spring-boot-webapp)

Comment: Could you add more info to your question?

Comment: @LaercioMetzner - updated my question

Answer (score 3):

spark-java does not directly support setting the context as a separate setting, but it still can be done. Probably the easiest way is to use the [Path groups](http://sparkjava.com/documentation#routes) as outlined in the docs.

Example from the documentation:

```
path("/api", () -> {
    before("/*", (q, a) -> log.info("Received api call"));
    path("/email", () -> {
        post("/add",       EmailApi.addEmail);
        put("/change",     EmailApi.changeEmail);
        delete("/remove",  EmailApi.deleteEmail);
    });
    path("/username", () -> {
        post("/add",       UserApi.addUsername);
        put("/change",     UserApi.changeUsername);
        delete("/remove",  UserApi.deleteUsername);
    });
});
```

So, by putting all route definitions within a `path`-call, you can easily set a context-like base-route for all your URLs. Theoretically, you could load this base-path (or context) from a configuration file, then it would be:

```
String context = myConfig.getContext();
path(context, () -> {
    get("/", getHome());
    ...
});
```